4-pin 12 V PC fan - manual speed control
I've been reading a little about 4-pin PC fans, but haven't been able to find a clear answer.
I understand the PWM pin controls the fan's running speed, so if I wanted to use a 4-pin fan for a non-PC related project, could I just connect the PWM to a 5 V source (maybe tap off the 12 V power using like a little voltage divider made of resistors) to force it to run full-speed? It'd be the same as having a PWM signal running at 100% duty cycle, I think?

It looks like you are not interested to control the speed but just set it to always run at full speed.
What you describe should work but there is an even easier way because the 4-pin PC fans are backwards compatible with 3-pin PC fans - just leave the pin open.
The PC fans are designed according to a publicly available standard (or at least a de-facto specification) and it defines that the fan must have an internal pull-up, so with nothing connected, the fan sees a 100% on signal.
This makes it compatible with 3-pin fans, and also allows driving the PWM inputs with open-drain outputs instead of push-pull outputs.

Perfect, exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much!

@myfingerhertz Note however, that many 4-pin fans will not behave well with a variable supply voltage (either PWM or analog), which was the old method for speed control.
